Minor alleles giving NA from R biomart getBM?
Does anyone know how to extract minor allele data from  grch38 ? the following gives NAs: library("biomaRt"); snp.db3 <- useMart(host = "https://www.ensembl.org/", biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_SNP", dataset = "hsapiens_snp");  nt.biomart3 <- getBM(attributes = c("refsnp_id", "minor_allele", "minor_allele_freq", "chrom_start", "chrom_strand", "associated_gene"), filters = c("snp_filter"), values = c("rs3762444", "rs284262", "rs655598", "rs12089815", "rs12140153", "rs788163", "rs1064213", "rs1106090", "rs7557796", "rs16825008"), mart = snp.db3, uniqueRows = TRUE);  nt.biomart3 The data is apparently available on Ensembl (e.g. https://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Variation/Explore?db=core;r=10:120308754-120309754;v=rs10788066;vdb=variation;vf=654619804) but the data extraction method only works if I use host = "https://grch37.ensembl.org" - otherwise it gives NAs for minor allele and minor allele frequency - is there something else I should do ? Or is there a better method ? Or is the minor allele data from grch37 actually up-to-date ?

Online Biomart (Martview) from Ensembl (https://www.ensembl.org/) doesn't show either this information :

That explains why you're getting "NA" with "biomaRt".
Online Biomart (Martview) from Ensembl GRCh37 (https://grch37.ensembl.org/) displays it :

Grch37 seems up to date (Release 112 (May 2024)).
To produce the preceding screenshots :

Go to https://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview or
https://grch37.ensembl.org/biomart/martview
Choose database -> "Ensembl Variation 112"
Choose dataset -> "Human Short Variants (SNPs and indels excluding
flagged variants) (GRCh38.p14)"
Filters -> "General Variant Filters" -> Tick "Filter by Variant name" and
specify the SNPs in the textbox
Attributes -> Variant -> "Variant Associated Information" -> Tick "Minor
allele (ALL)" & "Global minor allele frequency (all individuals)"
Push on the buton "Results" at the top of the page

If you want data from Grch38, you can try to scrape the data directly from "Ensembl.org".
### Packages
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

### SNPs to look for
look=c("rs3762444", "rs284262", "rs655598", "rs12089815", "rs12140153", "rs788163", "rs1064213", "rs1106090", "rs7557796", "rs16825008")

### Function to get the data
biomart=function(x){
  z=read_html(paste0("http://www.ensembl.org/homo_sapiens/Variation/Explore?v=",x))
  a= z %>% 
    html_element(xpath = '//span[.="Highest population MAF"]/following-sibling::span/b') %>%
    html_text2()
  if (is.na(a)) {b<-NA_character_}else{
    b = z %>% 
    html_element(xpath = '//span[.="Highest population MAF"]/following-sibling::span') %>%
    html_attr("title") %>%
    read_html() %>% html_text2()}
  data.frame(SNP=x,MAF=a,source=b)
  }

### Map operation
out=map(look,biomart,.progress = TRUE)

### Build the dataframe
output=bind_rows(out)

Output :
         SNP  MAF                       source
1   rs3762444 <NA>                         <NA>
2    rs284262 0.49 T in 1000GENOMES:phase_3:SAS
3    rs655598 0.49 A in 1000GENOMES:phase_3:FIN
4  rs12089815 0.50 G in 1000GENOMES:phase_3:EUR
5  rs12140153 0.18             T in gnomADg:ami
6    rs788163 0.42 C in 1000GENOMES:phase_3:LWK
7   rs1064213 0.50             A in gnomADe:nfe
8   rs1106090 0.50             A in gnomADg:amr
9   rs7557796 0.48 T in 1000GENOMES:phase_3:SAS
10 rs16825008 0.49 A in 1000GENOMES:phase_3:ITU

Notes :

operation takes approximately a minute to complete for these 10 SNPs
(ensembl.org servers seems overloaded) ;
rs3762444 is "NA" since there're 2 locations for this SNP. Some more
lines of code would be needed to fix this issue.


Many thanks (I will need some time to process this) ! Any chance you could indicate how you got the tables from Ensembl - I presume I have to go to Ensembl - Biomart - then select Dataset, Filters, Atttributes, then what ?

Sure. Post has been updated with these informations.

Brilliant ! The function definitely gives the required data for small vectors of SNPs (for R 4.4.0 it needs install.packages("pacman"); pacman::p_load_gh( "trinker/textreadr"). However, for long vectors it hangs - I've split a long vector and obtained all the data - so presumably this is because of unstable connection to Ensembl (?) - is there any way of adding something so that what has been done is not lost if the operation hangs ?

I assume Ensembl are facing high loads on their servers. Rate limits exist for their API and probably their website. There're several options to keep the results of the function if the operation hangs (i.e. : an error occurs). Keep a copy of each parsed webpage on your hard drive with write_html. You could later parse them again to extract the data. Or you can wrap the function with safely (https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html) or possibly (https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/possibly.html) from purrr to force its completion.

I think it's fair to open a new question with further queries concerning this - if you have time to answer then I look forward to reading some more from the new question.
